# RESTAPI Performance (Stress) test using docker

Tags: performance, docker, jmeter, load-testing, k6

I want to do a performance test on Perl based REST API. Is there any docker container available to do this?

Like I can input:
1000 requests per second
POST request URL and body
Run for 5 mins.

I have monitoring setup on the server side. If the client (docker image) also provides some monitors then its a plus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g.  Locust (https://locust.io) from container. Docs can be found here: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/running-locust-docker.html

Answer (score 1):

Docker doesn't provide any load testing capabilities per se, it's one of [virtualization options](https://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/definition/container-containerization-or-container-based-virtualization) mostly used for environmental integrity between DEV/QA/PROD systems. You might need this if you plan to dynamically add load generators using container orchestration solution like [k8s](https://kubernetes.io/).

Theoretically you can install any load testing tool into Docker container. Given your question tags:

- there is [k6 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/loadimpact/k6/)
- there are [multiple JMeter docker images available at Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=jmeter&type=image) (or you can [build your own JMeter docker image](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how))

Monitoring can be done using i.e. [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) tool.

Comment: Hello Dmitir, thanks for your answer. I am aware of the docker, but I want to avoid the setup. So just wonder if there is any docker readily available to start using directly